# Access is denied when user login as 'ADMIN' role but not in 'USER' role

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

**WebSecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String loginPage = "/login";
        String logoutPage = "/logout";

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(loginPage).permitAll()
                //.antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage(loginPage)
                .loginPage("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(logoutPage))
                .logoutSuccessUrl(loginPage).and().exceptionHandling();
    }
}
```

**MyUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) {
        User user = userService.findUserByUserName(userName);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : userRoles) {
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(roles);
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                user.getActive(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // getters and setters 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")

    private int id;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I got error Spring Boot security login. I got error in admin role login. But when I logged in user role it is working well. I don't understand why this is happening?

When I am trying to login as admin it redirects me `http://localhost:8080/error` page show this in body:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-09-11T14:10:05.108+00:00","status":999,"error":"None","message":""}
```

But when trying to login as user it works fine.

Comment: What URL do you call?

Comment: I called `http://localhost:8080/login`

Comment: Try to add `permitAll()` to `.formLogin()`.

Comment: I tried to add permitAll() but it gives me error in admin login

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may have messed up with antMatchers!!

In your code you've mentioned like

```
.antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER","ADMIN")
```

Which means both user and admin can have access to url's that match "/user/**" ie,. all url's with prefix "/user/"

If incase you have a url for admin which with "/admin/*
" , then you should give access to "/admin/**" too!

Then you have to add one more antMatcher like

```
.antMatchers("/admin/**).hasRole("ADMIN")
```

which will give access only to admin url's ie,. with prefix "/admin/**"